# error when using Mirrored strategy in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I read the data and processed it using the following code :

```
data = pd.read_csv('Step1_output.csv')
data = data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Res_pair'])

# creating instance of labelencoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
# Assigning numerical values and storing in another column
data1['Res_pair_ID'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(data1['Res_pair'])
data['Res_pair'] = data1['Res_pair_ID']
data = data.to_numpy()
train_X = data[0:data.shape[0],0:566]
train_y = data[0:data.shape[0],566:data.shape[1]]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[1], 1))
```

I build the model using following code where I have tried to distribute the dataset using mirrored strategy of Tensorflow :

```
print("Hyper-parameter values:\n")
print('Momentum Rate =',momentum_rate,'\n')
print('learning rate =',learning_rate,'\n')
print('Number of neurons =',neurons,'\n')

  

strategy = tensorflow.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
        model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
          tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64,kernel_size = 3,activation='relu',input_shape=train_X.shape[1:]),
          tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(neurons,activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(neurons,activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(neurons,activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(neurons,activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'),])
        sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=1e-6, momentum=momentum_rate, nesterov=True)
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy',tensorflow.keras.metrics.Precision()])
        results = model.fit(train_X,train_y,validation_split = 0.2,epochs=10,batch_size = 100)
        print(results)
       
    path = 'saved_model/'
    
    model.save(path, save_format='tf')

    for k in range(100):
        momentum_rate = random.random()
        learning_rate = random.uniform(0,0.2)
        neurons = random.randint(10,50)
```

I tried to run the code on GPU but it runs for some time and then throws this error :

```
Hyper-parameter values:

Momentum Rate = 0.6477407029392913

learning rate = 0.03988890117492503

Number of neurons = 35

Epoch 1/10
     1/270110 [..............................] - ETA: 28s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0100 - precision: 0.0100Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parallelised_script_realdata2.py", line 56, in <module>
    results = model.fit(train_X,train_y,validation_split = 0.2,epochs=10,batch_size = 100)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator) 
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 807, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1848, in _filtered_call
    cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1924, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 550, in call
    ctx=ctx) 
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (sequential/dense_4/Softmax:0) = ] [[nan nan nan...]...] [y (Cast_6/x:0) = ] [0]
         [[{{node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/else/_21/assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1270]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Update: The code works well if I don't use `strategy = tensorflow.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`. Like the code below (but will fail for larger datasets for memory shortage):

```
def convolutional_neural_network(x, y):
    print("Hyper-parameter values:\n")
    print('Momentum Rate =',momentum_rate,'\n')
    print('learning rate =',learning_rate,'\n')
    print('Number of neurons =',neurons,'\n')

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64,input_shape=train_X.shape[1:],activation='relu',kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(neurons,activation='relu')) # first hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='relu')) # second hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=1e-6, momentum=momentum_rate, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy',tensorflow.keras.metrics.Precision()])

    history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=10, batch_size=100)



momentum_rate = 0.09
learning_rate = 0.01
neurons = 40
print(convolutional_neural_network(train_X, train_y))
```

Update 2: Still facing a similar issue with smaller dataset

```
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 564, 64)           256
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 36096)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 50)                1804850
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 50)                2550
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 50)                2550
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 50)                2550
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 10)                510
=================================================================
Total params: 1,813,266
Trainable params: 1,813,266
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried decreasing batch size ? Can you provide the exact error message ? Is it running on CPU or GPU ?

Comment: Hi, I was able to resolve the memory issue. But still, it is throwing error as I edited and included. It is running on GPU.

Comment: You somehow get `nan` : this not a memory error. Is there any NaNs in the input data ?

Comment: No, there is no nan..the problem that I grabbed is the moment it starts training, it hits an error and I don't know why. The memory issue I have solved and edited here but the code  is still throwing error(and not running successfully)

Comment: The Nan make me think there is some missing / misformatted / corrupt data in train_y. Does it run in a _small_ subset of data you are 100% sure it is okay?

Comment: You definitely need to triple check X and y for nan, right before input in the model (after encoding). Can you try with a simple `Adam` Optimizer too ? Another test would be to try on a small subset (a few lines) to check if issue is data or model related

Comment: Thanks both of you.I am checking it out and will let know here.

Comment: It is working on the small subset of data when I am not using strategy = tensorflow.distribute.MirroredStrategy() else..it is throwing the error 
I cant train the entire dataset directly without distributing it as it is too big.

Comment: I also suspect as other's have mentioned that it might be due to `nan` values.Try using `tf.data.Dataset` api to load the data. This will not load the completed data in the memory and you will be able to train with even large amount of data with this. Try this api to read the .csv file. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset?version=nightly

Comment: still same issue.There is no null values,but still facing same issue.

Comment: Does decreasing the learning rate help?

Comment: Just for sanity check: Can you post some attribute of the data you are using, like: min, mean, std, and max of X and also for y?

Comment: the memory issues could maybe resolved using tf data api 
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance

Answer (score 1):

The model definition seems fine, so does the strategy.
Can you just verify train_Y for sanity check? Mostly I'm sure the error lies there.

If that's not the case, try running `model.fit` and latter ones outside the scope.